# How do you rank these actors?

Tags: knowledge, movies

Kickstarting [the fortnightly challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-movies?cb=1), here's a [movies](/questions/tagged/movies) puzzle.

The following actors have been ordered on a particular criteria:

> Gerard Depardieu
>   Damon Wayans
>   Jacques Perrin
>   Maurice Chevalier
>   Rod Steiger
>   Jean-Pierre Cassel
>   Matt Damon

Can you guess why they have been listed in this order?

**BONUS:**
Can you add a name somewhere in this list?

**HINT:**

> The title has a big clue. See if you can find it.

Comment: Is anyone trying to work this one out? Should I post a hint?

Comment: Hint, please.  I don't know where to begin.

Comment: I gave it a shot yesterday and I couldn't find anything tying more than 2 together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I've got it!  The trick to this was

> the title of movie the actor was in is based off the ranking system in US Army from top to bottom of the list the actors were in.

Gerard Depardieu

> Colonel Chabert (1994)

Damon Wayans

> "Major" Payne (1995)

Jacques Perrin

> A Captain's Honor (1982)

Maurice Chevalier

> The Smiling Lieutenant (1931)

Rod Steiger

> The Sergeant (1968)

Jean-Pierre Cassel

> The Elusive Corporal (1962)

Matt Damon

> Saving Private Ryan (1998?)

**BONUS!**

Mark Aldrich

> Gods and Generals (2003)

Comment: Rod Steiger is a Commander in the Longest Day, a Master Sergeant int 'The Sergeant (1968)', or his most prominent role as a General is in Mars Attack. (He also plays a General in the Girl and the General) - I'm pretty sure you need a rank that isnt already there.  EDIT: yup that seems right. allthough depending what army you're in, putting an LT above a Sergeant is.... well I guess it depends on the LT :P

Comment: @CodeNewbie, theres a bunch of names that could be added

Answer (score 3):

For the bonus :)

> James Cromwell: The General's Daugther (1999) (Placed at the very top of the list)

Comment: I like your bonus answer better, but you beat me to it. Haha